# The exception message is printed in an infinite loop

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, file-io, infinite-loop

I've been writing code that manually prints json (without the json library) after reading a CSV. It's to understand the structure for a project of this scale, which involves IO and Exception handling.

So, I've been debugging this snippet of code since yesterday. I've identified the problem, but have not been able to solve it.

I currently have an infinite loop after the exception message is printed. For context, in the part of the code that is missing, the user inputs the number of files and it creates an array of files. The snippet of code inside my message is a method which verifies if a csv has a an empty field. Count is there to count the line numbers, if count == 1 and there is an empty field, it will throw `CSVFileInvalidException`, which is a custom exception I made for this project. If count is bigger than 1, it throws `CSVDataMissingException`, i.e. another custom exception.

The timeline of the debugging goes as follows:

At first, when I had the infinite loop, I thought the regex caused my error, since I heard it could be badly implemented. I checked and each element is exactly what I want (a string, which represents a field in the csv). So, it wasn't regex since the behavior was normal.

Secondly, I realized I accidentally put my try block was inside my while loop, so I put it on the outside. No Luck. The issue still persisted.

Then, I figured out the issue. It read the line handled the exception and since there was no failsafe to exit the while loop, it did so non-stop.  So, I added an exit condition for the while loop. So, I added

```
if ((count > 1) && (s.nextLine() == null || s.nextLine().equals(""))) {
                    break;
                }
```

This checks if the line number is higher than 1 and if the nextLine is null or empty. I thought this had solved the infinite loop problem that I had. Once I implemented this, nothind after the regex ended up being outputted. I checked with multiple println().

I then realized I made a typo in one of the for loops. Now, I'm back to the same behavior it exhibited earlier. It's redoing the same sequence inside the while loop again. In this case, it's looping the message from `CSVFileInvalidException`, so i.e. `"The file called : " + f[i] + " is invalid. A field is missing. The file is not converted to JSON."`

So, I'm assuming there's something that doesn't make sense logically. I've tried multiple solutions and the exceptions are now never reached.

Sorry for the long code, the element that is being repeated is at the bottom, and everything else is inside the while loop, so I'm not sure if it's something I implemented there.

```
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        try {
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                lines = s.nextLine();
                if ((count > 1) && (s.nextLine() == null || s.nextLine().equals(""))) {
                    break;
                }
                //isolate the commas, and remove the quotes and extra space, so that the text remains clean and similar
                String[] line_parts = lines.replaceAll("^\"", "").split("\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?", -1);
                Cloned_Elements[] cloned_elements_array = new Cloned_Elements[line_parts.length];

                for (int z = 0; z < cloned_elements_array.length; z++) {
                    String[] array_ofstring = new String[line_parts.length];
                    for (int x = 0; x < array_ofstring.length; x++) {
                        array_ofstring[x] = "lol";
                    }
                    cloned_elements_array[z] = new Cloned_Elements(array_ofstring);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < line_parts.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (count == 1) {
                        if (line_parts[j].equals("") || line_parts[j] == null) {
                            ce.setCloned_array(line_parts);
                            throw new CSVFileInvalidException("The file called : " + f[i] + " is invalid. A field is missing. The file is not converted to JSON.");
                        } else {
                            if (j < line_parts.length) {
                                String[] length_1 = cloned_elements_array[j].getCloned_array();
                                cloned_elements_array[j].setCloned_array(line_parts);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (line_parts[j].equals("") || line_parts[j] == null) {
                            ce.setCloned_array(line_parts);
                            throw new CSVDataMissingException("In file " + f[i] + ", there is missing data in line #" + (count) + ". Thus, the file is not converted to JSON.");
                        } else {

                            if (j < line_parts.length) {
                                cloned_elements_array[j].setCloned_array(line_parts);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;

                }
        } catch (CSVDataMissingException e2) {
            System.err.println(e2.getMessage());
            try {
                p = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(js[js.length - 1], true));
                int line_nb = count+1;
                String[] error_array = ce.resize_string_arr();

                for (int x = 0; x < error_array.length; x++) {
                    if (error_array[x].equals("") || error_array[x] == null) {
                        error_array[x] = "xxx";
                    }
                }
                p.println("In file " + f[i] + " ,line " +line_nb + " is missing an element.");
                for (int z = 0; z < error_array.length; z++) {
                    p.print(error_array[z] + "   ");
                }

                p.println();
                p.println();
                break;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (CSVFileInvalidException e1) {
            System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
            try {
                p = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(js[js.length - 1], true));
                p.println("File " + f[i] + " is invalid.");

                String[] error_array = ce.resize_string_arr();
                for (int x = 0; x < error_array.length; x++) {
                    if (error_array[x].equals("") || error_array[x] == null) {
                        error_array[x] = "xxx";
                    }
                }
                p.println("Field is missing : " + error_array.length + " detected, 1 is missing.");
                for (int z = 0; z < error_array.length; z++) {
                    p.print(error_array[z] + "   ");
                }
                p.println();
                p.println();
                break;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: General comment: to another developer not familiar with your code, naming all your variables vague names like i, f, s, p, x, z etc means it's pretty much impossible to read this code and understand what it is the code is supposed to be doing. Take time to name your variables meaningful names to help others understand your code.

Comment: @KevinHooke, I usually do so. This was a combination of being inside a method and me focusing on implementation first. I usually follow best practices. I'll go edit it in a few minutes.

Comment: Actually, I disagree with what Kevin said.  All (?) of the variables that he has identified are either loop variables or local variables whose meaning is blindingly obvious from the context (e.g. `p.println()`).  It is (IMO) unnecessary to try to come up with meaningful names for variables whose meanings are obvious *from the context*.